# Odata > EF > Select SQL from table

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, odata

My POCO table definition is as follows and because I want to eventually use it as a virtual entity on Dynamics CE it should be able to use $expand on the OData endpoint on the below collections.

```
public partial class ak_iglead_V
{

    [Key]
    public Guid ak_igLeadId_V { get; set; }  //the pk
     ....
    public virtual ICollection<ak_Match> ak_MatchLead { get; set; }

}

public partial class ak_Match
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid MatchId { get; set; }
    public Guid ak_LeadId { get; set; } //Foreign key to 
    public Guid? ak_matchLeadId { get; set; } //forreign key to 
    public Guid? ak_matchContactId { get; set; }
    public decimal? ak_Confidance { get; set; }
    public string ak_Name { get; set; }
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly"),ForeignKey("ak_LeadId")]
    public virtual ak_iglead_V ak_iglead_V { get; set; }
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly"),ForeignKey("ak_matchLeadId")]
    public virtual ak_iglead_V ak_iglead_V_matched { get; set; }
}
```

The problem however comes when I want to return the object to the controller: The SQL that get generated from the above definition looks like this :

```
SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[m].[MatchId] AS [MatchId], 
[m].[ak_LeadId] AS [ak_LeadId], 
[m].[ak_matchLeadId] AS [ak_matchLeadId], 
[m].[ak_matchContactId] AS [ak_matchContactId], 
[m].[ak_Confidance] AS [ak_Confidance], 
[m].[ak_Name] AS [ak_Name], 
[m].[ak_iglead_V_ak_igLeadId_V] AS [ak_iglead_V_ak_igLeadId_V], --generates error column does not* exists
[m].[ak_iglead_V_ak_igLeadId_Vmatched] AS [ak_iglead_V_ak_igLeadId_Vmatched] --column does not exists
FROM [dbo].[ak_Match] AS [m]
```

This is the code snippet:

```
`public List<ak_Match> Matches { get; set; }
 public void Initialize()
{
    var matches = from m in db.akMatches
                  select m;
    this.Matches= matches.ToList() ;
`
```

and generated the exception because it cannot find the columns that was supposed to be the collection.

Can it not get ignored in the SQL for the collections or forreign key's somehow?
Somehow because the are the same table's key im thinking its somehow confused.

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException:
>   An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
>
> SqlException:
>
> Invalid column name 'ak_iglead_V_ak_igLeadId_V'
>   Invalid column name 'ak_iglead_V_ak_igLeadId_Vmatched'

Comment: Can you provide the table DDL?  Does it have foreign keys?

Comment: I added the 'ak_iglead_V' table with its PK, the two fieds 'ak_LeadId'  & 'ak_matchLeadId'  are the foreign key to the this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship between your Navigation Properties and Foreign Key Properties doesn't follow EF's convention, so you need to configure the relationship explicitly.  EG with a [ForeignKeyAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 0):

the ak_match table should handle the foreignkey to the same ak_igLead_v entity: 
notice the [ForeignKey] attributes pointing to the named nvigation properties,

```
public partial class ak_Match //V_CE_ak_match
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ak_MatchId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FK_ak_Match_ak_igLead_V")]
    public Guid ak_LeadId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FK_ak_Match_ak_igLead_Matched")]
    public Guid? ak_matchLeadId { get; set; }
    public Guid? ak_matchContactId { get; set; }
    public decimal? ak_Confidance { get; set; }
    public string ak_Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("ak_MatchLead")]
    public virtual ak_iglead_V FK_ak_Match_ak_igLead_V { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("ak_MatchedLead")]
    public virtual ak_iglead_V FK_ak_Match_ak_igLead_Matched { get; set; }
}
```

@david - that pointed me in the right direction.